# Why is <tfoot> only shows in the last page when printing?

Tags: printing, bootstrap-table

I am trying to print a html using dompdf and I am trying to add a footer but the footer only shows only the last page in print view? Is it a chrome bug?

```html
 <table class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" style="color:black">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col"  style="border-top: color: white; border-left: color: white;border-right: color: white;"  colspan="4">                    </th>
                </tr>
            
            
             <tr class="text-center">
                    <th scope="col" class="align-middle" ></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="align-middle text-nowrap">Reference No.: BatStateU-FO-ESO-01</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="align-middle text-nowrap">Effectivity Date: January 3, 2017</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="align-middle text-nowrap">Revision No.: 00</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
             <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <p class="title-tab"><input type="checkbox" style=" transform : scale(2);"> &nbsp; Extension Service / Training is requested by clients.</p> <br> 
                    <p class="title-tab"><input type="checkbox" style=" transform : scale(2);" checked> &nbsp; Extension Service / Training is Department’s initiative.</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
             </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                   <th scope="col" colspan="4"> </th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey, I got the same question, plus my `<tfoot>` doesn't even become displayed in the HTML as if it's not there in the source code! Have you come to a solution yet?